# change iframe url with javascript . firefox issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I have a main page that loads a default link in an iframe  `http://mypage.com/myurl`. Having it in a blog, I want to dynamically change that default link inside the iframe, for every post page.  I load the default link like that:

```
<iframe width='1000' height='500' name='iframename' frameborder='0'
        src='http:/mypage.com/myurl'></iframe>
```

(works on all browsers) and i change dynamically the link inside the iframe by putting this code in every post page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.iframename.location = "http://mypage.com/mynewurl"; 
</script>
```

It works fine on chrome and ie, but it does not work on firefox!!

Any ideas or work around?

Here a simplified example [www.tinyurl.com/9l7zt2n](http://www.tinyurl.com/9l7zt2n)  see the difference with firefox it loads the default link in the iframe. ie and chrome can change with the added javascript.

If it helps to test it on the blog  [www.tinyurl.com/9axhquh](http://www.tinyurl.com/9axhquh)  u can see it working on chrome and ie, if u click on any post title or "read more" to load the post's page, the iframe on top changes accordingly

Any ideas or work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.iframename.location` is probably not supported crossbrowser.

try:

```
<iframe width='1000' height='500' id='iframeid' frameborder='0' src='http:/mypage.com/myurl'></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('iframeid').src = "http://mypage.com/mynewurl";
</script>
```

this means:

1. accessing an element by name through a `document.elementName` syntax is not supported.
2. an iframe element has no property called `location`. `location` is a property of `window`. You can access the `window` of an `iframe` by using using `contentWindow`.

I've written a short test here http://jsfiddle.net/FyNW9/. Run it in different browsers.

Comment: thanks @Roman it does work, but if i change to iframe id instead of iframe name, some other links that I also have in each post in the form of : <a href="http://mypage.com/mynewurl" target="iframeid">Click here</a>
<a href="http://mypage.com/mynewurl" target="iframeid"><img alt=""  src="thumb.jpg" /></a>                                             open in a  new window instead of inside the iframe on ie and firefox.  on chrome it works fine.   And that was the reason for using iframename.  Is there a way to make those links to work with iframeid too?

Comment: Actually by adding a function like : function changeSource(newSource) {document.getElementById('iframeid').src = newSource;}      I got the link working as : <a href="#post" onclick="changeSource('http://bing.com')">Click here</a><br />   working example here: http://tinyurl.com/92e6va5   So thanks Roman its working everywhere now